# How to delete specific map field in an array?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I created an firestore collection with users, and in this one I save favourites for an favourite list by an array, and the favourites get created as map fields of this array, and I want to know how I can remove an specific favourite (map field) of my array?

That is my function to add favourites to my array.

```
addFav(name, performer, category, room, abstract, begin, dis, color, btn, id`){
try{
  this.afs.doc(`users/${this.user.getUID()}`).update({
favs: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
  name,
  performer,
  category,
  room,
  abstract, 
  begin, 
  dis,
  color,
  btn
})
  })
}
```

I need help to delete an specific favourite / map field of my array

```
deleteFav()
{
  try{
this.afs.doc(`users/${this.user.getUID()}`).update({
  favs: firestore.FieldValue.delete()
})
  }
}
```

following pictures shows my firestore collections with the array and the map fields.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y1Xj.png

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrayRemove method like:

favs: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("performer")

Check this one:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: Alright thank you, and how do i get the specific id of my map field? Because i want to remove an whole map field, take a look on the image i added.

Comment: Can you add complete image. Your image is badly cropped, didn't reveal all the information.

Comment: i just fixed it by creating an collection instead of arrays, its less complicated, but thank you anyway.